# Laptop overheating and shuts down

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card

I have [this laptop](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-Pro-15-N580GD/), it should be pretty strong in terms of gaming, for some reason it's far from it.

Every time that I l do something that requires a bit of computation, such as playing a game, even if it's CSGO all low quality and the resolution is 800x600, the fans go berserk and after a while of "suffering" it will show Windows' "Locking..." screen and then just turn off, I think it's due to temperature but I'm not sure.

Worth mentioning that it also happens on Linux (I have both Windows & Linux).

What can cause this? How can I fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It says it can come with i7 and 16GB of memory. That should suffice to run most any application. Overheating happens with two different operating systems. So I suggest calling ASUS support

Comment: But before that update the Nvidia drivers in Windows and also install them in Linux, something that I bet you didn't.